# Extension of a real analytic function to a complex analytic one in a bounded domain

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $f$ be a real analytic function defined on an open interval $I=(a,b)$ with $a,b$ finite.

Is it always possible to extend $f$ to a complex analytic function defined on an open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, such that $I\subseteq U$ and there is $\epsilon >0$ such that all open disks of center $x\in I$ and radius $\epsilon$ are included in $U$?

If this is not the case, what about the following apparently weaker statement: Given $f$ as above, for every $\delta>0$  there are a complex analytic extension of $f$ defined on some $U\supseteq (a+\delta,b-\delta)$ and $\epsilon >0$, such that  all open disks of center $x\in (a+\delta,b-\delta)$ and radius $\epsilon$ are included in $U$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How about $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$?  You can’t create analyticity at the boundary without input.

Comment: Yes, I see. On a second thought, the radius of convergence of a complex analytic function from any $z_0$ is the distance of $z_0$ from the nearest singularity, right?  So it should suffice to consider $\epsilon$ to be the distance of the nearest singularity to the interval $(a,b)$. Assuming the set of singularities is not dense, $\epsilon$ should be positive. (*Edit*:  changed 'diameter' to 'radius' in the question).

Comment: $\epsilon \to 0$ as $x \to a$ or $x \to b$; note that one has easy counterexamples with bounded analytic functions too by taking the (translation of the) usual $e^{-1/x^2}$ at both ends (eg $e^{-1/(x-a)^2}e^{-1/(x-b)^2}$); in general given a real analytic function on $(a,b)$ there is a plane open set $U$ where $f$ extends but $U$ is not a piece of a strip in general (in other words $U$ not included in $ (a,b)\times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon >0$)

Comment: @Conrad. I see the problem. But this still leaves the possibility of $f$ being defined on a strip $(a',b')\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, for *any* $a'>a$ and $b'<b$ and $\epsilon$ equal to the distance of the nearest singularity to $(a',b')$. Which is the second part of my question.

Comment: That is true - for any compact interval $[c,d]$ included in $(a,b)$ one can find such (take the radiuses at each $x$ and cover $[c,d]$ by finitely many such etc) but your second part has probably a typo as it is only about end $a$ so it is a bit confusing

Comment: Thanks. If you were willing to write this as an explicit answer, I would be glad to accept it. (NB: typos fixed in the question).